# Passing objects from one private method to another

Tags: java, object, methods, private

I have been programming for a little while now, and I have a question on the use of public methods. I am working on a vending machine program, and I have a private method `setUpMachine()` to initialize the game and set up the objects. I have another private method `startMachine()` that starts the game and prompts the user for input. It then passes the input to yet another private method `checkInput()` that checks to see if the input is valid... but this is where I run into not so much of a "problem", but a weird feeling of me not doing something correctly. I need access to the objects that are in my first method, `setUpMachine()` for my third method `checkInput()`. The problem is that I have many objects (candy, chips, soda, cookie), and passing them all to check perimeters just doesn't seem right. In other words, doing this:

```
checkInput(FoodType candy, FoodType chips, FoodType soda, FoodType cookie)
```

doesn't seem right. Does this mean, that if I use private methods, I have to pass objects every time I want to use them? I read that making public methods is bad practice.

An explanation on this would be nice, not so much an explanation telling me my coding is inefficient, but more an explanation describing *when* and *how* to use private methods, or if there is another way to go about doing this.

Comment: If those objects will be present in all the methods of your class (or most of them), then you can set them as attributes in your class and provide them to the instance on the constructor.

Comment: So if I am going to use the objects throughout the class, it is ok to initialize the objects outside of the setUpMachine() method, and just in the class? Then is the setUpMachine() method even necessary?

Comment: You can set the class attributes in the `setUpMachine` too. That will depend on your design, but IMO it would be better to do it in the constructor in order to avoid using these attributes in a method before you have set them before.

Comment: Yes they can either be static or instance variables on the class - a `private` method cannot be called outside of the class itself, but has access to all properties of the class. A bit more info - `protected` is accessible within the package, and `public` is globally accessible.

Comment: Ok that really clears things up. Thank you :)

Comment: @doublesharp there's a big difference between `static` and `non-static` attributes: `static` methods/variables belong to the class itself, `non-static` methods/attributes belong to the class instance (the object). Any `static` variable can be called and used (and be modified) by any instance of the class or any other method, and all of them will share **the same object instance**. For this problem, OP needs to set those as `non-static` variables in order to have different vending machines.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm very aware of the difference between `static` and `non-static` properties, however both are available to private methods on a class. We don't know that he doesn't want to have some global shared attribute that is static, while others are instance variables. The question was about public/private methods, not static vs instance variables.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza See the update to my answer - it uses instance variables for the FoodType variables and a static variable for an error message used in the Exception.

Comment: @doublesharp if you're aware of the difference, then guide OP in the right direction. And for any error messages you should use a property file and a class that loads those messages, not `static` variables, but that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree, it was more of an example and I didn't want to write a full implementation of program as an example. My point was that both static and non-static properties are available to private methods. For all we know VendingMachine is a singleton and has static FoodType objects that contain the name and quantity of different items within the larger scope of a program that runs a single vending machine. Or not.

Comment: @doublesharp not if you're in a store with multiple `VendingMachine`s. The tendence (even in singleton classes) is to have `non-static` attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to pass the objects around, you can configure them as instance variables:

```
public class VendingMachine {
    private FoodType candy;
    private FoodType chips;
    private FoodType sodas;
    private FoodType cookies;

    private static String errorMessage = "A really bad error occurred.";

    public VendingMachine(){
        this.setupMachine();
    }

    private void setUpMachine(){
        this.candy = new FoodType();
        this.chips = new FoodType();
        this.sodas = new FoodType();
        this.cookies = new FoodType();
    }

    private boolean checkInput(){
        if (this.candy==null || this.chips==null || this.sodas==null || this.cookies==null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public void doSomething() throws Exception() {
        if (!this.checkInput()) throw new Exception(VendingMachine.errorMessage);
        // do things
    }
}
```

This class can then be called as

```
VendingMachine vendingMachine = new VendingMachine();
try {
    //vendingMachine.checkInput() is not available because it is private
    vendingMachine.doSomething(); // public method is available
} catch (Exception e){
    // validation failed and threw an Exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, public methods should be used when you want to expose something to the outside world. Typically, it is a more high level method, where the private methods are used to provide the details. Private methods can be easily changed without impacting other classes, where public methods cannot.

Consider the example

```
public void run() {

  setUpGame();
  validateInput();
  doSomethingInteresting();
  endGame();
  notifyUserGameIsComplete();

}
```

In this example, `run` is public, but none of the other methods are. This is because callers of the public method only know they want to run the game but are not concerned with the details of exactly how it works.

Having many private methods is ok for sure. Methods should be single focused and each only do one thing. That allows you to read, debug and maintain the code more easily.

If multiple methods need to share data, you can declare them as member variables of the class. This means they are state of the class. For example:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;

   public String getName() { return name; }
   public boolean nameMatches(String pattern) { // do some regex testing against the name }
}
```

In this example, the methds share access to `name`, and `name` is a part of the person.

If you really need to pass a bunch of parameters, you can create an object to hold all of them. So instead of passing param1, param2, param3, etc, you could create a data transfer object, such as

```
class MyStuff {
   private final String param1;
   private final String param2;
   private final String param3;
}
```

Now you can pass `MyStuff` around as a convenience rather than listing individual parameters.

Hope this helps add some clarity.

Answer (score 2):

The private methods are not visible to the ouside world. You can only invoke the private methods from the methods of the same class.

Private methods can be used to logically break down a big method into a number of smaller pieces (steps).

Also if you have some code that seem to repeat in multiple methods in your class then you can make use a private method.

You don't need to define an object as a parementer of the private method if the object is also a field in the class, but if not then you have to.